# Filtrar letras de un objeto- JS

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones

Tengo un array de objetos donde quiero filtrar los que tenga el color rojo y los que en su nombre tengan la letra n y la a. estoy atorado para la parte de las letras

```
const ovejas = [
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'alan', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'nina', color: 'rojo'}
]
function fitra(oveja){
  let buscaColor= ovejas.filter((col)=> col.color =='rojo')

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta así:

```js
const ovejas = [
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'alan', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'nina', color: 'rojo'}
]

function filtro(array) { 
  
  const apla = array.filter(arrayJr => arrayJr.color=='rojo')
  const final = apla.filter(aplita => aplita.name.toUpperCase().includes('N') ||
  aplita.name.toUpperCase().includes('A')) 
  
  return final
} 

console.log(filtro(ovejas))
```

Comment: Sería bueno que expliques tu respuesta, poner solo código no es recomendable porque difícilmente habrá un aprendizaje. Además, en el primer filtro cambias el color de todos los elementos, debería ser doble signo igual `==` y, finalmente, creo que se podría lograr con un solo filtro.

Comment: Comparto tu idea, no he tenido tiempo para explicarlo detalladamente. En cuanto al filtro errado, ya lo arreglé.

Comment: Me funciono con la compuerta logica && y tengo una duda. Por que hay que hacer mayusculas las lestras en el filtrado?

Comment: Lo estoy seteando a mayúsculas para evaluarlo así, también podrías setearlo a minúsculas.

Comment: No hay necesidad de hacer dos filters, en uno solo puedes condicionar todo, buena solución

Comment: No tendría que retornar también el primer índice `{ name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' }` por tener el string a ?

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal quieres que se cumplan todas las condiciones, entonces puedes agregar el `test` de una regex como `/(?=.*n)(?=.*a)/gi` a la condición del `.filter`

```js
const ovejas = [{"name":"Noa","color":"azul"},{"name":"Euge","color":"rojo"},{"name":"Navidad","color":"rojo"},{"name":"Ki Na Ma","color":"rojo"},{"name":"alan","color":"rojo"},{"name":"nina","color":"rojo"}];

const res = ovejas.filter((e) => e.color == 'rojo' && /(?=.*n)(?=.*a)/gi.test(e.name));

console.log(res);
```